# How can I restart a process If any exception occured in previous running process file(nohup.out) using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have one Jar file in SERVICE_PATH directory.Currently it is running .Suppose any exception or below exception occurred,then i need to kill the current process ,delete the nohup.out file from the directory & then restart the same jar.
Below is my sample code.using below code some time it is working but sometime it is not working.

I will schedule my autoRestart.sh file in crontab.

What is the best way to do this?

```
#! /bin/sh
    SERVICE_PATH=/app/application/DataAdapter
    STOPPED_MESSAGE="java.net.UnknownHostException"
    File='/app/application/DataAdapter/nohup.out'
    
    chmod a+x "$File"
    processId=$(ps -ef | grep 'dataAdapter' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }')
    echo "$processId"
    
    if [ $processId -eq $(ps -ef | grep 'dataAdapter' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ printf $2 }')] 
    then
    
        if grep -Fxq "$STOPPED" "$File"
        then
            echo "Process Id New---$processId"
            kill -9 $processId
            rm -rf $File 
            nohup java -jar dataAdapter.jar &
        else
            #nohup java -jar dataAdapter.jar &
                echo "Msg if not found"
            echo "Process Id New---$processId"
    
        fi
    else
        kill -9 $processId
        rm -rf $File
        nohup java -jar dataAdapter.jar &
            echo "processId not found"
    fi
    echo "Task Finished"
    echo $$
```

Comment: Your "`if grep -Fxq "$STOPPED" "$File"`" use "`STOPPED`" variable and you has defined "`STOPPED_MESSAGE`" variable

Comment: Also, warning, for security, when using `rm` command. It is better to use quotes around `$File` (like your `grep` command) preceded by the special option `--` (see `man rm`)

Comment: Do you use `sh` or `bash`?